# How to integrate angular js and twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying integrate angular js and twitter bootstrap, but the file is not executed as required. I have included my angular.min.js file downloaded from https://angularjs.org/ in js folder of bootstrap. I have      attached my code below.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="gemStore">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div class="product row">
   <h3>
      {{store.product.name}}
      <em class="pull-right">{{store.product.price}}</em>
   </h3>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.product=gem;
});
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here:

Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```js
(function(){
var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
var app = angular.module('gemStore', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.product=gem;
});
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div class="product row">
   <h3>
      {{store.product.name}}
      <em class="pull-right">{{store.product.price}}</em>
   </h3>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not directly answering question but certainly useful hint.

Comment: My output is {{store.product.name}} {{store.product.price}}

Comment: @Dr.AxE I'm not sure for what do you need boostrap in your question  but please see my update answer is shows how to add boostrap ui to your code

Comment: It is just a part of my code..So i need bootstrap.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, try changing the jQuery version to something above 1.9.
If you are using angular 1.2.18+ then you can keep older jQuery just load angular before jQuery

Shaping up with AngularJS. Its a good course, you must go through all the videos.
Here is the complete project with gulp server thrown in, Try it out. It has bootstrap running with angular
https://github.com/sirajc/gemstore_codeschool_angular

Comment: the example is taken from code school angularjs video. its not working in my case

Comment: My output is **{{store.product.name}} {{store.product.price}}**

Comment: AngularJS is not bootstrapping, hence the output is not evaluated, Can u see any error in console and share the error here

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///E:/Softwares/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///E:/Softwares/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/bootstrap.min.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///E:/Softwares/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/angular.min.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///E:/Softwares/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/app.js